# How can I use NSDictionary's methods to add objects and keys?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary

I want to make an NSDictionary that has the following values where symbol & id are my keys.

I want to map "AAPL" to symbol
I want to map 100 to id.

```
"AAPL":symbol
"100":id

"GOOG":symbol
"101":id

"YHOO":symbol
"102":id
```

How can I create a dictionary of these values with

> dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys

Comment: And don't forget that you can create an NSMutableDictionary and add entries one at a time with setObject.

Comment: C'mon, if you know NSDictionary exists, then you know how to browse the API reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you describe would most likely be represented by an array of dictionaries, since the keys would be repeated for each entry.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"APPL", @"symbol", @"100", @"id", nil], [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"GOOG", @"symbol", @"101", @"id", nil], [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"YHOO", @"symbol", @"103", @"id", nil], nil];
```

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't look at it that way. Could be he meant that, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Which one is key, which one is value? Assuming you want map symbol to id, then

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"100", @"AAPL", // 100 is object, AAPL is key
                         @"101", @"GOOG",
                         @"102", @"YHOO",
                         // etc...
                         nil];
```

If the IDs are numbers, use

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt: 100], @"AAPL",
                         // etc...
                         nil];
```

If, OTOH, you want to map ids to symbols, then reverse the entries:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"AAPL", @"100",
                         @"GOOG", @"101"
                         // etc...
                         nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the ids as the keys and the symbols as the values, this should work:

```
 NSDictionary *stocks = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"AAPL", @"100", @"GOOG", @"101", @"YHOO", @"102", nil];
```